# Return only top facet results

Tags: solr

In a faceted search many facets may be returned:

```
<lst name="provider_id">
    <int name="18"> 39843 </int>
    <int name="1"> 18398 </int>
    <int name="5"> 6949 </int>
    <int name="6"> 5274 </int>
    <int name="16"> 2717 </int>
    <int name="4"> 2333 </int>
    <int name="11"> 2107 </int>
    <int name="13"> 2095 </int>
    <int name="17"> 433 </int>
    <int name="12"> 408 </int>
    <int name="9"> 50 </int>
    <int name="14"> 0 </int>
    <int name="2"> 0 </int>
</lst>
```

How might I limit the output to only the top 3 facets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `&facet.limit=3` (or whatever other number you want to use).

By the way, the default value for this parameter is 100; if you want to return an unlimited # of facet results, use a negative number.

Here is a complete list of parameters one can use with the Simple Faceting toolkit included in Solr:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters

Comment: He should also do [`facet.sort`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.sort) depending on his Solr version.